# Проверяемые безударные  гласные

Tags: орфография, егэ

Знакомый старшеклассник задал мне вопрос, на который я не смог ответить. Прошу коллег о помощи. На одном из солидных сайтов по подготовке к ЕГЭ в вопросе А-14 нужно указать строку, на которой все слова на одно правило - правописание безударных проверяемых гласных в корне. Из 4-х предложенных вариантов 1-я и 2-я строки выглядят так:
1.Сож…леть; соб…лезновать; состр…дать 
2.Изд…вна; издр…вле; исст…ри
Мне думается, что оба варианта здесь содержат ТОЛЬКО слова на безударную проверяемую гласную, т.е. здесь ошибка в подборе слов для вопроса. Однако сайт дает правильный ответ - 2-я строка, а первая строчка - ошибочный ответ. Как я уже писал, сайт этот серьезный, уважаемый. Может быть, в чем-то я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Чем больше знаешь, тем трудней решать тестовые задания.

Comment: "Солидный сайт" - сайт ФИПИ, разработчиков КИМов ЕГЭ и ГИА. Остальные - блоги учителей и репетиторов, где ошибки возможны по разным причинам. Если знаете еще толковые ресурсы, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: >"Солидный сайт" - сайт ФИПИ
>Чем больше знаешь, тем трудней решать тестовые задания.
Чего ж именно я еще должен не знать, чтобы решить А9?

Какое сочетание слов является грамматической основой в одном из
предложений или в одной из частей сложного предложения текста?
1) стали машины (предложение 5)
2) корабли в упор палили (предложение 2)
3) вывести из строя (предложение 3)
4) матросы старались завладеть (предложение 4)

Comment: (3)Поскольку энергии ядер редко хватало на то, чтобы вывести корабль из
строя, бой мог заканчиваться и абордажем. (4)При этом с атакующего
корабля, сцепившегося своим бортом с бортом противника, на вражескую
палубу высаживались матросы, которые в рукопашной схватке старались
завладеть неприятельским судном. (5)… промышленная революция XIX века
очень быстро внесла коррективы в эту область военного дела, и первым
важным нововведением стали паровые машины.

Comment: Я не понял сути Вашего комментария и приведенного примера из А-9. Неточный вопрос? Два или более вариантов ответа? Нет правильного варианта? Слишком "тупые" варианты ответов? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это я ЛарF написал, задние из демо-варианта с сайта ФИПИ.
Все ответы, полагаю, неверны. Если четко следовать заданию.
Так что либо задание неправильно сформулировано, либо ответы неправилные.  
Привести основы всех предложений просто не могу, их там достаточно много - и они достаточно спорные. Но вот именно таких, как в предложенных вариантах ответов, там нету:  
1) машины стали - неполно, - *стали нововведением*,   
2) "в упор" - не относится к основе    
3) "из строя" - не относится к основе    
4) это вообще из разных предложений    
Вероятно подразумевался ответ 3), хотя черт их знает...

Comment: Мне кажется, что "вывести из строя" - это как раз и есть грамматическая основа, ведь в данном случае мы имеем устойчивый оборот речи

Comment: Авторы, видимо, тоже так думают.
если "попасть пальцем в небо" - основа тоже будет включать и "палец" и "небо"? 
Моя беда только в том, что не знаю, чему детей сейчас учат. То то, что делают это крайне непоследовательно и путано, - факт.

Comment: Я ничего ни о каком конкретном задании не писала! 
Но вполне согласна с Виктором.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ошибаетесь. Очередная плюха в ЕГЭ. Хорошо хоть в "материалах к".

Не знаю, как Виктор проверял (что ж не написали-то?), но проверочное есть: стрАдный, прилагательное к "страда". Страда и страдать - однокоренные.

ЗЫ А парень - молодец. Утер нос дядям из министерства.

~~~~~~~

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), я и не говорил, что вы писали что-то про конкретное задание.
ладно, проехали.

Обснуйте, если не затруднит, почему "вывести из строя" - это грамматическая основа. Надеюсь не потому, что это "устойсивое выражение"? Я пример приводил: "попасть пальцем в небо" - это тоже по такой логике основой будет?

Comment: Слово "страдать" я бы проверил "стрАждущий" или даже "стрАсть"

Comment: Ну в вобщем-то, да, если копнуть. Но для школьника, боюсь, не очень убедительно.  
Страсть - это вообще можно оспорить, родство древнее и не совсем ясное. На таком уровне проверять вокализм современных слов нельзя без дополнительных оснований.       
А страждущий - царковнославянизм, не знаю, как там в школе с понимаением этого...

Comment: Для Ларисы: мне нравится сайт Яндекса. "ЕГЭ-2013". Вот ссылка 
http://ege.yandex.ru/russian

Comment: Страда тоже этимологически однокоренное,(как и страсть) в современном русском значения разошлись, проверить страдный нельзя. Страдать, сострадать - словарные (пишутся так по традиции). Что старославянизмами нельзя проверять - школьники знают, так же как и про полногласие/неполногласие - в программе это есть.

Comment: >проверить страдный нельзя  
Это еще почему???  
Ну насчет страсти и прочего - тут еще можно как-то понять, соглдаситься или не согласиться...  Но объяснеть **невозможность** проверить традицие... Это уже слишком.
Страда - время когда страдают (тяжело и много работают). Более того, сам глягол страдать, судя по всему, является производным от "страда", даже не наоборот.

Comment: Дело не в сайте, а в характере самого задания. Я бы его вообще изменила на  "В каком ряду пишется такая-то буква", и пусть ребенок проверяет доступными ему словами, или запоминает, лишь бы правильно писал. Вот это я и имела в виду, говоря, что человек, никак в своем сознании не соотносящий слово "страда" со словом "страдать" сделает правильно, а тот, кто знает и понимает - допустит ошибку. Аналогичное задание  в ГИА по поводу НН. Там слово "странный"  НЕВЕРНО  объяснить образованием от основы на -Н с помощью суффикса Н.

Comment: Виктор, спасибо. Прошла по ссылке, но ничего, кроме тестов-онлайн с ответами не нашла. Причем сразу же расхотела решать эти тесты. Вариант ударения дОлбит выдается как верный.

Comment: Спасибо, Лариса. Я попытаюсь более критически отнестись к указанному сайту и посмотрю тесты более внимательно. Раньше я там особых ляпов почти не замечал.

Comment: По поводу замены на причастный оборот. В последнем заменить нельзя. т.к. слово "который" употреблено с предлогом.
По поводу СПП с последовательным подчинением. Не поняла, в чем сложность?Вот оно: А спросить-ка, даст ли ей хоть копейку вот та дама, которая сидит в карете? По поводу сказуемого: Я действительно считаю, что фразеологизм "попал пальцем в небо" является сказуемым.  И не только я.

Comment: Это я знаю, что с предлогом. А вот кто сказал, что нельзя, если я вам дал вариант замены?!  

Бедные детеи. Их учат запоминать правила, как дать правильный ответ на неправильный вопрос. Вмсесто того, чтобы учить думать...

Answer (score 2):

1.Сож…леть-жалость;
 соб…лезновать - боль;
 состр…дать - непроверяемая гласная. Или Вы как-то проверили?
Ответ-2.

Comment: Слово "сострадать" я бы проверил "стрАждущий" или даже "стрАсть"

Answer (score 0):

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), "дОлбит" Яндекс выдаёт как правильный, но вопрос поставлен так: "Где ошибка?" Так что нет претензий к этому слову. Вопрос в другом: вот в том же самом первом вопросе есть слово "принятА", и оно является правильным (то бишь без ошибки). В Викисловаре допустим и вариант "прИнята". Я, конечно, понимаю, что Викисловарь не самый надёжный источник, ибо его могут изменять все, но всё же. По-моему, именно вариант "прИнята" постоянно звучит у дикторов на телевидении, а ведь у них есть специальные словари. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Валентин, я предполагаю, что телеведущие (сейчас, насколько мне известно, дикторов нет) чаще всего произносили слова "прИнято (решение), прИняты (законы) и т.п., а мы ведь даже новостные программы слушаем краем уха, поэтому сложился стереотип, что все однокоренные слова с данным значением произносятся с ударением на первом слоге. Не так часто даже по телевизору употребляют слово "принята" (что еще можно сказать, кроме "принята программа"?). Так что, думаю, и у Вас сложилось впечатление, что дикторы сознательно нарушают акцентологические правила.

Comment: >@Ларf, "дОлбит" Яндекс выдаёт как правильный   

Этого достаточно, чтобы составить мнение о Яндексе.

Comment: Фразеологические обороты являются одним членом предложения, потому что их можно заменить одним словом."Вывести из строя" - сломать, "попасть пальцем в небо" - не угадать. Глагольные фразеологизмы в предложении являются сказуемым. "Ты попал пальцем в небо= Ты не угадал". В обоих предложениях простое глагольное сказуемое. Аналогично в односоставном безличном: оборот является главным членом односоставного предложения. Все логично.

Comment: И школьная грамматика ни при чем. В учебниках для вузов говорится о том же. Например, у Валгиной:"Синтаксически фразеологические сращения выступают в роли единого члена предложения".

Comment: О Яндексе. Наверное, я была невнимательна в прочтении ответа. Там дословно так:  "В каком слове допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: неверно выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук?
Вы ответили правильно:
дОлбит". 
Я заново вопрос-то не перечитывала. Но рядом написанные слова "правильно -дОлбит" вызвало во мне такую реакцию (не может быть правильно!!!) Прошу прощения, что ввела в заблуждение.

Comment: >Фразеологические обороты являются одним членом предложения, потому что их можно заменить одним словом."Вывести из строя" - сломать, "попасть пальцем в небо" - не угадать.   

Погодите-погодите... Вы серьезно считаете, что "попасть пальцем в небо" - это все всместе один член предложения только потому, что его можно заменить одним словом?

Я уж не говорию, что "вывести корабль из строя" - это совсем не сломать. Это то, что на суще связано со словом "нестроевой". А на море - строй это боевой порядок, применяющийся до сих пор как походный...

Comment: Тем не менее считаю, что так оформлять ответы нельзя. Сам вопрос повторяется мелким шрифтом и выше основного поля ответа, а ответ выглядит, например, так:"Правильно:
по обоим сторонам" Что должен зрительно запомнить ребенок?

Comment: Там и без этого плюх хватает.
http://ege.yandex.ru/russian/game/3

Любое можно **заменить**...
В четвертом случае: "не подверженное влиянию героя".

А это вообще вызывает разжижение "мосха"
http://ege.yandex.ru/russian/game/5